# Do I have to rebuild entire Robot again if I die?

Tags: starbound

I just died in the fight against the inactive robot. Now he is gone. Do I have to rebuild the whole thing again?  Please don't tell me that. I Googled it but found nothing.

Only answers with evidence will be accepted.

Comment: In current version, i died 5 times before killed bone dragon, it wandered off one time, i had to look for him. try to fight bosses near your spawn location.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. If you lose to a boss in starbound, you currently have to construct the summoning item again to re-try the boss. Happy grinding!

Comment: i saw a few lets plays and there people died against the UFO and it was still there when they came back. Are you sure ? where do you have the information from ?

Comment: and lets assume this is right, how about i beam to the ship just before i dye .. will he then be there or gone again ?

Comment: Are you sure? My friends have told me that the UFO summon is non-consumable (I haven't made it that far myself yet).

Comment: I just did the UFO fight again last night and the distress beacon disappears once you activate it.  The first time I fought it in an earlier version I did have to re-craft it.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=deaWiFAtkxY this video at 2:40 shows how someone dies and he is still there.

Comment: This game is in beta, as far as I know it is supposed to dissipear

Comment: @user2664856 Not able to view the video, but maybe if they are playing multiplayer, it doesn't de-spawn unless every player dies/leaves the area?

Comment: all these hypotheses seem legitimate but i am seeking an answer that is definitive and provable

Comment: @user2664856 - The video is pretty clear.  It entirely depends if you spawn on your ship or on the planet after you die.

Comment: @Ramhound - that could really be the answer. Why dont you post this as an answer and not as a comment ?

Comment: @user2664856 - I don't answer questions on games in a beta status.  Any answer I provide won't be accurate once out of beta.

Answer (score 0):

Use starcheat to get back the robot.

I beamed to the ship because I wanted to figure out if you have to kill it first, then back after 10 seconds googling and it was gone within that time.

If you are not supposed to be able to escape a boss fight by beaming back and forth to the ship (and healing, or whatever) then they should disable the beam. Makes no sense that the robot disappears immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I only have my experience to work from but I can confirm that in the latest build (Enraged Koala (from April ?)) the first two bosses both disappear if you die.

Given the costs involved in summoning the bosses, this has lead me to do my research before summoning the later bosses, so I don't know if they disappear too, although it seems likely.